# Cannot change background color in my "Color Flipper" game program

Tags: javascript, html, css

The color flipper is a simple game in which the user clicks a button and the background color changes. But I don't know why I am not able to do so. I think that there probably something wrong in my logic but as I am new to this I don't know if it's the logic or just a syntax error.

```js
function changeColor(){
    //let clr= ['green', 'orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red']
    var random= Math.round(Math.random(0,5))
    switch(random){
        case 1: document.body.style.backgroundColor= "red"
        break;
        case 2:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "green"
        break;
        case 3:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "yellow"
        break;
        case 4:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "blue"
        break;
        case 5:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "pink"
        break;   
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body >
 <div class="container">
    <h2>Background Color: <span class="color"></span></h2>
    <button  onclick="changeColor()">Click Me</button>
 </div>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

change your `random` var to be;

`Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;`

You can read more about it here;

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeColor(){
    //let clr= ['green', 'orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red']
    var random= Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    switch(random){
        case 1: document.body.style.backgroundColor= "red"
        break;
        case 2:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "green"
        break;
        case 3:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "yellow"
        break;
        case 4:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "blue"
        break;
        case 5:  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "pink"
        break;   
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body >
 <div class="container">
    <h2>Background Color: <span class="color"></span></h2>
    <button  onclick="changeColor()">Click Me</button>
 </div>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this!
@Dexterians

Comment: Why "like this"? You should explain to the OP why your code will work for them, you are more likely to get an accepted answer if your code is what they are looking for if they can understand why your code is working for them.